# Integrating gcc 4.8 with Xcode 4.x

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP in a objective-c++ program. 
Unfortunately llvm-gcc 4.2 seems to have serious bug when working with OpenMP. According to my researches, the best solution should be using gcc 4.8 instead.

I already downloaded a prebuilt version of gcc 4.8. My question is: how can I integrate the new compiler with Xcode, so that I can select it directly in Build Settings from Xcode? 
Alternatively, is there an **easy** way I can compile my project with gcc4.8? I have different files and a .xib, I really do not want to compile all of them by hand.

I'm using MacOS 10.8.3 and Xcode 4.5.1 (though I think the procedure should be the same for all Xcode 4.x).

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, in your project, select the project (the root of the files, with the blue icon).
In the view that opens, select the project again, then select the tab "Build Settings".

Search here the entry "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C (there is a search box above the table view). Edit the value and set a custom path (by selecting "Other…") to the gcc you downloaded.

Comment: Thanks, however I get the error: "Unsupported compiler '/path/usr/local/bin/g++' selected for architecture 'x86_64'
Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file /path/main.m of type sourcecode.c.objc...." (same for other source files I have)

Comment: Does the gcc you downloaded have support for Objective-c(++)?

Comment: Well, it actually seems it doesn't! (though I wonder why to compile a gcc version for MacOS without including Objective-C(++) ). I'll try to compile gcc 4.8 from source and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

install GCC 4.8 into Xcode 4.5, Xcode 4.6, Xcode 5.0:

for people who have not install GCC 4.8:

install the new version of home-brew

you can find the method how to install on the Internet

update your brew to the latest version (`$brew update`)

1.`$brew install gcc48 --enable-all-languages`

(may should install mpc, mpfr and gmp through brew, http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/)

2.`$brew link gcc48`

3.backup g++,gpp,c++,cpp,c++ in `/usr/bin/`

4.[optional step]:

alias  g++-4.8,gpp-4.8,c++-4.8,cpp-4.8,c++-4.8

from `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/g++`

to `/usr/bin/`

**[above 4 steps for the developer who have not install gcc]**

5.make plugin

1)download  [a plugin of GCC 4.5 for Xcode](https://code.google.com/p/xcode-gcc-plugin/downloads/detail?name=GCC%204.5.xcplugin.zip&can=2&q=)

2)change every "4.5" to "4.8", "4_5" to "4_8", the file names, the file contents,

except "com.apple.compilers.gcc.headers.4_2” in the file `GCC 4.5.xcspec`.

you can remain contents in `English.lproj` unchanged, and delete `Japanese.lproj`.

3)in file `GCC 4.8.xcspec`

(hope you have already change the file name of `GCC 4.5.xcspec` to `GCC 4.8.xcspec`)

change `ExecPath = "...”;`

to `ExecPath = "/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8"`

or `ExecPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.2/bin/gcc-4.8"` (for the people who install gcc-4.8 by brew)

or `ExecPath = "/usr/bin/gcc"` (for the people who finished step 4.)

4)delete “-Wshorten-64-to-32” part in file `GCC 4.8.xcspec`

```
{
    Name = "GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION";
    Type = Boolean;
    DefaultValue = NO;
    CommandLineArgs = {
        YES = (
            "-Wshorten-64-to-32",
        );
        NO = ();
    };
    AppearsAfter = "GCC_WARN_PROTOTYPE_CONVERSION";
    Category = Warnings;
    CommonOption = NO;
    DisplayName = "Implicit Conversion to 32 Bit Type";
    Description = "Warn if a value is implicitly converted from a 64 bit type to a 32 bit type.
    [GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION, -Wshorten-64-to-32]";
}
```

6.put edited `GCC 4.8.xcplugin` into

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Plugins/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/`

7.reopen Xcode.

Now, the new plugin has already prepared for you. You can see your new GCC compiler plugin in the  "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" of "Build Settings" of your project

8.change Build Settings in Xcode project

1)In the `project` and `target` settings in Xcode

change "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" to "GCC 4.8"

2)In the `project` settings

delete “CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" row