# how to delete CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY row in xcode

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am trying to use gcc-4.8 with xcode and followed the steps in [Integrating gcc 4.8 with Xcode 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247721/integrating-gcc-4-8-with-xcode-4-x)

Am stuck at the last step which asks to delete the CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY row. Delete button doesn't seem to help. ANy pointers?

The exact problem is reported here http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/08/how-to-suppress-xcode-emitting-stdlib-flag/

I am attempting to build using GCC 4.8 from within Xcode, following this procedure (only using version 4.8 instead of 4.7).

After fixing a few minor build failures, my project compiles correctly, but linking fails with the following error:

g++-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
The -stdlib= flag is supported by LLVM, but not GCC, hence the error.

In Build Settings, there is a CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY flag under the User-Defined heading. When I change the value of this flag, the error changes to reflect the current value. However, I cannot remove this flag from the project entirely.

Is there a way to stop Xcode from emitting the -stdlib= flag?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Why are you trying to use GCC with Xcode?

Comment: Xcode 5.. I want to use the openMP support which seems to be missing with clang. I got this issue resolved by going to the project settings and deleting the flag instead of target settings.

Comment: Aha, glad you got it figured out.  OpenMP support has been developed for Clang by Intel (http://clang-omp.github.io) but has not been merged into the main version.

Comment: How exactly did you get rid of the -stdlib argument? If I set the flag for "link with standard libraries" to No, it still gives me the error. I am also trying to use OpenMP with Xcode5

Comment: Same problem.. Arun, can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6.1.1, you can delete the CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY flag in the project settings but not in the target settings. To change from target to project, there is a button just above the buttons labelled "Basic" and "All".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, search around and found this old thread.

To delete `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY`, just simply select the flag and press `command + delete`.