# Xcode: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib='

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11

I am getting `unrecognized command line option '-stdlib='` error when trying to compile my project. I already disable `linking with standard library` option, but `-stdlib=` flag is still there.

[image]

```
g++-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib='
Command /usr/local/bin/g++-4.8 failed with exit code 1
```

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar thread that is to get rid of `-stdlib=` flag.

I found the answer and post the solution there.

[how to delete CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY row in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559908/how-to-delete-clang-cxx-library-row-in-xcode/32930991#32930991)