# Installing GCC 4.8 with Xcode 5.1

Tags: gcc4.8, xcode5.1

Yesterday i've installed the update 5.1 for Xcode and after reinstalling the gcc 4.8 using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247721/integrating-gcc-4-8-with-xcode-4-x/22354492#22354492) (which work with X5.0) don't work anymore.

Have you any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

GCC is not support Xcode 5.1 anymore according to Apple document! I try to install Riak and suffer this problem.
Anyway, you may try to write a plug-in refer to the link: [How to use a recent GCC with Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061966/how-to-use-a-recent-gcc-with-xcode-5)