# Specify to Xcode which binaries to use for compilation

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to specify in Xcode which binaries to use for compilation? I have recently cross-compiled `clang`, `ld`, `libtool`, etc, and I want to test them.

I am fully aware that I could just do something like:

```
/Path/To/My/Tools/clang -c file.c
/Path/To/My/Tools/ld file.o -o executable
# or
/Path/To/My/Tools/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -o myLib.a *.o
# and so on...
```

However I am looking for a way to integrate this nicely into Xcode. As my tools should (technically - this is what I want to test) be equivalent to the built-in tools, I don't need to change any of Xcode's default compilation args, etc. I just need to tell it to find the binaries some place other than `/usr/bin` or somewhere in the `${SDKROOT}` or `*.xctoochain` directories. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project setting for this. In your Xcode project, open the "Project Navigator" and click on the icon for your project. It should show the project settings. In the "Project" section of the project settings, click on the "Build Settings" tab. Type "compiler" into the search field, and it should show you the "Build Options" setting for "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C". It defaults to Apple LLVM 5.0, but you can change it. Click on "Default (Apple LLVM 5.0)" and select "Other…" It will pop up a text field where you can enter the path to your own tools. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks like exactly what I was looking for. However, when I set the path to: `/mytools/bin/clang`, I get the following error whenever I try to build the project: `Unable to determine concrete GCC compiler for file`. I feel there may be a subtlety I'm missing...

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247721/integrating-gcc-4-8-with-xcode-4-x) suggests the problem might be that the compiler was built without Objective-C/C++ support. Not sure if that would be your issue, too. If not, you can always add a Build Rule to your targets to use a particular compiler for C/C++/Objective-C/Objective-C++. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Ah I see - some of the projects I'm looking at are old Open Source projects so that could well be the issue. The build rule idea is great, I hadn't even considered that! If I can't fix up the compiler issue, that sounds like the best course of action, cheers!